# Where is a good demo for SQL CE Replication?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce

Can someone please point me to a demo or walkthrough of SQL 2008 R2 replication with SQL CE.

The idea at our end is to have clients that will connect daily to our server and replicate / synchronise their data.

Thanks.

Comment: I know you mentioned replication, but maybe Microsoft's Sync Framework might work for you... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can find something usable here:

http://erikej.blogspot.com/search?q=Replication

Blog owner Erik Ejlskov is SQL CE MVP in Denmark.

Comment: I recommend Rob Tiffany's book for Merge Replication

Comment: Very interesting, so SQL compact 4 doesn't support merge replication, so where to from here? They mention it like this 'due to time and resource constraints', so does anybody know, will future versions or future service packs add this back in?

Comment: For who need more informations about the SQL CE 4 REPLICATION, this can be useful: http://erikej.blogspot.com.br/2014/01/entity-framework-6-sql-server-compact.html

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at something similar and found this from 2004. It's a bit old and I haven't tried it but it might lead you on to the right path.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838193.aspx

Answer (score 0):

i know in the answer you mention that the link says SQL Compact 4 doesn't support merge replication, but if you actually try it, it seems to work fine (for me at least).  I can't see anything anywhere about plans to add it, maybe they slid it in?